# "Mirroring" a PShape object (rotation / translation issue) with Processing

Tags: rotation, geometry, processing, translation

I would like to "mirror" a PShape object like in the picture below:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/kwTQ7vA.png]

I know how to display multiple shapes and how to invert them (screenshot below) but things get complicated when I have to rotate them (and probably translating them) so as they "stick" to the preceding shapes (first picture).

[image]

I've been trying to compute an angle with the first 2 vertices of the original shape (irregular quadrilateral) and the `atan2()` function but to no avail.

I would really appreciate if someone could help figuring how to solve this problem.

```
int W = 20;
int H = 20;
int D = 20; 

PShape object;


void setup(){
    size(600, 600, P2D);
    smooth();

}


void draw(){
    background(255);

    pushMatrix();
    translate(width/2, height/1.3);

    int td = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        translate(0, td*H*2);
        scale(-1, 1);
        rotate(PI);
        object();
        td *= -1;
    }


    popMatrix();

}


void object() {
    beginShape(QUADS);

    vertex(-20,  20);
    vertex(20,  0);
    vertex(20, -20);
    vertex(-20, -20);

    endShape();
}
```

Comment: If it is possible for your project I would suggest a different approach. Create the final shape to be draw without rotations, but with regular calculus.

Comment: @J.D. Please do, any suggestion is welcomed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do what you want you have to create a shape by 2 given angles for the top and the bottom of the shape `angleT` and `angleB´. The origin (0,0) is in the center of the shape. This causes that the pivots for the rotations are in the middle of the slopes of the shape :

[image]

```java
int W = 40;
int H = 40;
float angleT = -PI/18;
float angleB = PI/15;

PShape object;

void object() {

    float H1 = -H/2 + W*tan(angleB);
    float H2 = H/2 + W*tan(angleT);

    beginShape(QUADS);

    vertex(-W/2,  -H/2);
    vertex(W/2, H1);
    vertex(W/2, H2);
    vertex(-W/2, H/2);

    endShape();
}
```

When you draw the parts, then you should distinguish between even and odd parts. The parts have to be flipped horizontal by inverting the y axis (`scale(1, -1)`). The even parts have to be rotated by the double of `angleB` and the odd parts have to be rotated by the doubled of `angleT`. For the rotation, the center of the slopes (pivots) have to be translated to the origin:

```java
void setup(){
    size(600, 600, P2D);
    smooth();
}

void draw(){

    background(255);

    translate(width/2, height/2);

    float HC1 = -H/2 + W*tan(angleB)/2;
    float HC2 = H/2 + W*tan(angleT)/2;

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++){

        float angle = (i % 2 == 0) ? -angleB : -angleT;
        float HC    = (i % 2 == 0) ? HC1 : HC2; 

        translate(0, -HC);
        rotate(angle*2);
        translate(0, -HC);

        object();
        scale(1, -1);
    }
}
```

The algorithm works for any angle, positive and negative including 0.

[image]

---

This algorithm can be further improved. Let's assume you have a quad, defined by 4 points (`p0`, `p1`, `p2`, `p3`):

[image]

```java
float[] p0 = {10, 0};
float[] p1 = {40, 10};
float[] p2 = {60, 45};
float[] p3 = {0, 60};

PShape object;

void object() {
    beginShape(QUADS);
    vertex(p0[0], p0[1]);
    vertex(p1[0], p1[1]);
    vertex(p2[0], p2[1]);
    vertex(p3[0], p3[1]);
    endShape();
}
```

Calculate the the minimum, maximum, centerpoint, pivots and angles:

[image]

```java
float minX = min( min(p0[0], p1[0]), min(p2[0], p3[0]) );
float maxX = max( max(p0[0], p1[0]), max(p2[0], p3[0]) );
float minY = min( min(p0[1], p1[1]), min(p2[1], p3[1]) );
float maxY = max( max(p0[1], p1[1]), max(p2[1], p3[1]) );

float cptX = (minX+maxX)/2;
float cptY = (minY+maxY)/2;

float angleB = atan2(p1[1]-p0[1], p1[0]-p0[0]);
float angleT = atan2(p2[1]-p3[1], p2[0]-p3[0]);

float HC1 = p0[1] + (p1[1]-p0[1])*(cptX-p0[0])/(p1[0]-p0[0]);
float HC2 = p3[1] + (p2[1]-p3[1])*(cptX-p3[0])/(p2[0]-p3[0]);
```

Draw the shape like before:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){

    float angle = (i % 2 == 0) ? -angleB : -angleT;
    float HC    = (i % 2 == 0) ? HC1 : HC2; 

    translate(cptX, -HC);
    rotate(angle*2);
    translate(-cptX, -HC);

    object();
    scale(1, -1);
}
```

[image]

---

Another approach would be to stack the shape on both sides:

[image]

For this you have to know the heights of the pivots (`HC1`, `HC2`) and the angles (`angleB`, `angleT`). So this can be implemented based on both of the above approaches.

Define the pivot points and the directions of the top and bottom edge:

```java
PVector dir1 = new PVector(cos(angleB), sin(angleB));
PVector dir2 = new PVector(cos(angleT), sin(angleT));
PVector pv1  = new PVector(0, HC1); // or PVector(cptX, HC1)
PVector pv2  = new PVector(0, HC2); // or PVector(cptX, HC2)
```

Calculate the intersection point (`X`) of the both edges. Of course this will work only if the
edges are not parallel:

[image]

```java
PVector v12  = pv2.copy().sub(pv1);
PVector nDir = new PVector(dir2.y, -dir2.x);
float   d    = v12.dot(nDir) / dir1.dot(nDir);
PVector X    = pv1.copy().add( dir1.copy().mult(d) );
```

The stack algorithm works as follows:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){

    float fullAngle = angleT-angleB;

    float angle = fullAngle * floor(i/2);
    if ((i/2) % 2 != 0)
       angle += fullAngle; 
    if (i % 2 != 0)
        angle = -angle; 

    float flip = 1.0;
    if (i % 2 != 0)
        flip *= -1.0;
    if ((i/2) % 2 != 0)
        flip *= -1.0;

    pushMatrix();  

    translate(X.x, X.y);
    rotate(angle);
    scale(1, flip);
    rotate(-angleB);
    translate(-X.x, -X.y); 

    object();

    popMatrix();
}
```

Comment: Hi @Rabbid76, happy new year thanks for the reply. Unfortunately this answer implies that the angle between the 2 irregular vertices of the quadrilateral is fixed, and as a result, that the geometry of the PShape object is not flexible. I should have been more specific but the question is about mirroring any kind of quadrilateral with various angles. See a live example here: https://vimeo.com/34121761

Comment: @solub I added a new approach to the answer.